# .on method in jquery IE8 bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

```
$(function() {
  var inputChecked = "skills__label_checked",
      radioChecked = "education__label_checked",
      elemsInput   = $(".skills__input_checkbox, .education__input_radio");

  function setLabelClass() {
    elemsInput.each(function(i, e) {
      $(e).parent('label')[e.checked?'addClass':'removeClass']
      ($(e).is(':radio')?radioChecked:inputChecked);
    });
  }

  elemsInput.on('change', setLabelClass);
  setLabelClass();
});
```

This works fine in all modern browsers include IE9+, but doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? The 2.x branch dropped support for IE8.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, jQuery v1.10.2

Comment: What isn't working? I believe there was an IE bug at some point that wouldn't fire the change event until the control lost focus. Is this what is happening?

Comment: @Jason: IE doesn't adds class to Label when we click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 (and older too) is quite buggy on change event :

> IE 5-8 fires the event when the checkbox or radio is blurred, and not
>   when it is activated. This is a serious bug that requires the user to
>   take another action and prevents a consistent cross-browser interface
>   based on the change event on checkboxes and radios.

Ref: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html

Try change your event handler from `change` to `click` or try to fix the behavior forcing the change event to fire (not tested):

```
  $('.skills__input_checkbox, .education__input_radio').click(function () {
        // Cause the change() event
        // to be fired in IE8 et. al.
        this.blur();
        this.focus();
   });
```